# Where is the OldStandard SmallCaps font located when it is used in pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno, a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{OldStandard}

\begin{document}
 \textsc{This is a Small Caps text. Where Is This Font Located?}
 
 \textbf{\textsc{Even Bold Font Works On Small Caps Font. How?}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I went into the installed fonts directory of TexLive and these are the fonts. But pdflatex can still load this amazing font somehow and delivery bold version of the SC font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno, a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf}]{Old Standard}

\begin{document}
    Normal text\\
    \textsc{This is a Small Caps text. Where Is This Font Located?}

    \textbf{\textsc{Even Bold Font Works On Small Caps Font. How?}}
\end{document}
```

The font used can be found here: https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/83760/monotype-modern-extended-italic

The full log is here: https://pastebin.com/HmLJyV2E

Comment: Look into your log file. It tells you which fonts pdflatex loads.

Comment: OT1/OldStandard-TLF/b/sc is the font it seems. Is there a way to use it in XeLaTeX? I am trying to find posts where I saw how to import fonts like this in XeLaTeX but I can't find the right search keywords it seems

Comment: @Masum If you want to use the fonts in XeLaTeX, just do the same thing as in pdfLaTeX: Load the `OldStandard` package. The package automatically detects that it's used in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and loads the right fonts. If that doesn't work, try LuaLaTeX, there the font lookup rules are much saner.

Comment: I would have done that. I want to use a different font for normal/italic font but all the rest including math font should be in Old Standard. But if I use \setmainfont[ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf]{Old Standard}, then I get the error that fontspec cannot detect the font specified even though it is in the same directory.

Comment: Compile with lualatex and then show the log-file.

Comment: here is the full log: https://pastebin.com/HmLJyV2E
edited the question to include the new testing code, log and font link

Comment: the image you show of the directory listing doesn't show extended italic, where did you put it?

Comment: sorry for the late response, was off. The italic font was in the same directory, which is recognized by fontspec if I use it like this \setmainfont[BoldFont=OldStandard-Bold.otf,ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,BoldItalicFont=ModernMTStd-BoldItalic.otf,]{ModernMT-Extended.otf} i.e., with the otf extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look into the log file, you see the following:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/oldstandard/OldStandard-Bold.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/oldstandard/OldStandard-Regular.pfb>
```

Thus the only files `pdflatex` uses are regular and bold pfb fonts, not the small caps.  Browsing `OldStandard.map` gives you

```
OldStandard-Regular-tlf-sc-ot1--base OldStandard-Regular "AutoEnc_uj34jtfpfn5yennazvty6te5mb ReEncodeFont" <[ost_uj34jt.enc <OldStandard-Regular.pfb
OldStandard-Regular-tlf-sc-t1--base OldStandard-Regular "AutoEnc_ra2ua52s7rbqxjp3us4is2jhlc ReEncodeFont" <[ost_ra2ua5.enc <OldStandard-Regular.pfb
```

etc.

These cryptic lines tell the following story:  small caps in pdflatex OldStandard are in fact "fake small caps".  Pdflatex uses capital letters from different design sizes to emulate small caps.

Comment: I wouldn't call them "fake small caps", they are specially designed to be small caps glyphs. They are just in the same font file since OpenType generally handles small caps by a font feature substituting some glyphs instead of completely separate fonts, therefore the conversion to Type 1 format also contains both kind of glyphs and can select them by simply changing the encoding.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, I use 'fake' as a description, not in a disparaging sense.  Fake small caps are the fonts that use for lowercase the same letters as for uppercase.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that is not the case for Old Standard. These are different glyphs specifically for small caps. They are never used for uppercase.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, I am afraid this is incorrect.  otfinfo -f `kpsewhich OldStandard-Regular.otf` gives "c2sc Small Capitals From Capitals".  Compare this with Cabin-Regular.otf:  "smcp Small Capitals".  Cabin has real small caps, while OldStandard (at least in TL distro) has fake ones.

Comment: OldStandard-Regular.otf has (at least on my system) both features, c2sc and smcp. In any case, c2sc is unrelated to fake small caps: "smcp" activates "normal" small caps where capital letters stay the same and lowercase letters are replaced with small capitals, while c2sc leaves lowercase letters untouched and replaces capital letters with small capitals (This is intended e.g. for abbreviations which are sometimes set as small caps, even though they are also already written in capitals).

Comment: In any case, type1 version definitely uses fake small caps...

Comment: At least on my system, the `.enc` file used for the `-sc-` fonts loads glyphs with names like `a.sc`, `b.sc`, `c.sc` which are the separate small caps versions of the glyphs and at no point tries to load another size of the font.